# How to get all grandchildren of one parent via while loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have one object `A`, which is a parent.
This `A` parent has two children, `B` and `C` (maybe more than 2). Each of these children has their own children, they have their own, and so on. But each line stops at one object `X`, which has a special property.
I need to get all `X` elements when I click on object `A`.
My code works only for children of `B`, but not for `C`.

Please help me to get all X elements of A's all children!

```
def get(self, request, pk):
    A = Object.objects.get(pk=pk)
    childs = A.parents.all()        
    X = []
    while childs:
        for c in childs:                
            if c.type_of_trakt.name == 'ПГ':
                X.append(c)
            childs = c.parents.all()
            break
    serializer = PGListSerializer(X, many=True).data
    return Response(serializer)
```

Comment: How come you're assigning a variable called `childs` to `A.parents.all()`? Aren't those opposites?

Comment: no, parents - is a related name of A's children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand all your code, but based on what you have, when you are iterating through `childs`, you assign `childs = c.parents.all()` partway through the loop, abandoning any former elements of `childs` that you hadn't checked yet.

Instead of that you could add them to a new list of childs to be subsequently processed:

```
def get(self, request, pk):
    A = Object.objects.get(pk=pk)
    childs = A.parents.all()        
    X = []
    while childs:
        newchilds = []
        for c in childs:
            if c.type_of_trakt.name == 'ПГ':
                X.append(c)
            newchilds += c.parents.all()
        childs = newchilds
    serializer = PGListSerializer(X, many=True).data
    return Response(serializer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the loop after one iteration. So your code executing only for B (which is first one).

```
def get_special(self, childs, X):
    for c in childs:                
        if c.type_of_trakt.name == 'ПГ':
            X.append(c)
        sub_childs = c.parents.all()
        if childs:
            X = self.get_special(sub_childs, X)
        else:
            return X

def get(self, request, pk):
    A = Object.objects.get(pk=pk)
    childs = A.parents.all()        
    X = []
    X = self.get_special(childs, X)
    serializer = PGListSerializer(X, many=True).data
    return Response(serializer)
```

Comment: *"you need to use recursive functions not a while loop"*: recursion is just one way to do it, but it is certainly possible to do it with loops, like is usually the case with a breadth-first traversal.

Comment: Yeah you are right, making the edit. Thanks!